# connecting a block with gr_complex output to a block with numpy_complex input

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to connect a block that (written in cpp) and outputs a gr_complex value, to a block (written in python) that uses a numpy.complex as input.

I get the following error,

---

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/runtime_swig.py", line 4569, in primitive_connect
    return _runtime_swig.top_block_sptr_primitive_connect(self, *args)
ValueError: itemsize mismatch: ofdm_sync_long0:0 using 8, gen_diff_fft_win0:0 using 16

---

sizeof(gr_complex) is 8 bytes and sys.getsize(numpy.complex) returns 32 bytes. Could this be the reason for the error ?

Is it possible to use gr_complex type in python ? It would be easier for me to make changes in the python block as opposed to the CPP block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use numpy.complex64 as dtype instead; that's the native type identical to gr_complex (which is a complex composed of two 32 bit floats).

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. It works perfectly when I use numpy.complex64.