# connecting a python block with a cpp block makes gnuradio stop

Tags: python, c++, signals, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have two gnuradio OOT blocks. When connected to each other, my flowgraph stops almost immediately without displaying any error, as follow.

```
Generating: '/root/top_block.py'

Executing: /usr/bin/python -u /root/top_block.py

*Two or three logs that match starting procedure of both blocks*

>>> Done
```

When the two blocks are disconnected, or used separately, everything works fine.

The first one is written in python and output `out_sig=[np.complex64]`

The second one is written in C++ and input `io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(gr_complex))`

I have experienced a similar problem while connecting two OOT blocks with pmt messages, and the reason was a different type of pmt message as output/input. This is why I'm looking at the type of data being exchanged. However it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35347751/10196690) that `gr_complex` and `numpy.complex64` are equivalent so maybe I'm not looking in the right direction.

Comment: if the signatures were incompatible, you'd not get to the point where both blocks `start()`, as they could not be connected. So, yes, looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Any other idea on what can cause this issue ?

Comment: not with the lack of insight into what your blocks actually do, no.

Comment: what type of error might stop the flowgraph without causing any error in the log ?

Comment: any, basically!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code which is sufficient to reproduce the problem (i.e. both blocks). Right now, any answer would be speculation.